# How to set event listener while choosing a file other that (change) event in Angular

Tags: angular, file-upload

I'm trying to set a popup validation for my file upload and now i am using (change)=method($event) as the event listener, the problem here is its only triggering when the input file changes its not triggering when I choose same file next time,How to solve this?

<input #inputFile type="file" name="uploadFile"
(change)="fileInputChange($event,docu.id,inputFile)" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I see no reason to retrigger the popup validation on selecting the same file, since nothing really changed and validation will return the same, you can add this to the `input` element in html:

`(click)="$event.target.value=null"`

It will actually remove the input's value when user clicks the input element, and the `change` event will, thus, always treat the selected file as new.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clean your input in fileInputChange method.

Exemple:

```
@ViewChild('inputFile', { read: ElementRef }) inputFile!: ElementRef;


fileInputChange(...) {
  ....

  this.inputFile.nativeElement.value = '';
}
```